# Build a tags list using UICompositional layout iOS | Remove empty space within groups

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building a list that contains hashtags using the `UICompositionalLayout`, I have managed to achieve dynamic-sized cells in my sections using the `estimated` metrics. Which looks like this

[image]

However, I want to remove the empty spaces between the tags and have a continuous stream spanning over two rows. Here is how I am building my layout section

```swift
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(120), heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        layoutItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
        let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.43), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.35))
        let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
        let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        return layoutSection
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Horizontal scrolling variable-width cells will have complications with any approach. You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72606531/6257435

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for replying. I tried your code, but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: *"unfortunately did not work"* -- what didn't work?

Comment: Umm the cells were not distributed over 2 rows and they overlapped with each other

Comment: Hmmm... I just copy/pasted the example code from that answer into a new project... worked fine, producing the same output as the posted images.

Comment: Oh! Let me try it again, I will get back to you on it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UI components are great -- until they're not.

Something such as a `UICollectionView` is designed to layout and manage a large number of items (cells).

When the layout doesn't match the *desired* layout, though, it can become a fight against the built-in design of the component. That's the case here.

As you know, by default, a horizontal scrolling collection view aligns the cells like this:

[image]

Trying to get the cells left-aligned with equal spacing from row-to-row is not easy, whether using Flow or Compositional layout.

You might want to take a different approach -- here's one idea...

We'll start with a simple "self-selectable Tag View":

```
class MyTagView: UIView {
    
    public var selectChanged: ((MyTagView) ->())?
    
    public var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            theLabel.text = text
        }
    }
    
    public var normalForegroundColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 78.0 / 255.0, green: 164.0 / 255.0, blue: 145.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    public var normalBackgroundColor: UIColor = .white
    public var highlightForegroundColor: UIColor = .lightGray
    public var highlightBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 78.0 / 255.0, green: 164.0 / 255.0, blue: 145.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    private let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor
        theLabel.textColor = normalForegroundColor
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 40.0),
        ])
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = normalForegroundColor.cgColor
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    @objc func gotTap(_ sender: Any?) {
        selected.toggle()
        selectChanged?(self)
    }
    var selected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if selected {
                backgroundColor = normalForegroundColor
                theLabel.textColor = normalBackgroundColor
                layer.borderColor = normalBackgroundColor.cgColor
            } else {
                backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor
                theLabel.textColor = normalForegroundColor
                layer.borderColor = normalForegroundColor.cgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which gives us this:

[image]

It also has a closure so we can inform its parent / controller when the selected state has changed.

Next we'll create a "Tags View" that will use a vertical stack view with horizontal "row" stack views to layout the tags:

```
class MyTagsView: UIView {
    
    public var delegate: MyTagsViewDelegate?
    
    public var tagViews: [MyTagView] = []
    
    var theTags: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            // clear existing (in case we're setting the tags multiple times)
            vStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
                v.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            tagViews = []
            var totalWidth: CGFloat = 0
            // create individual tag views and get the total width
            theTags.forEach { str in
                let t = MyTagView()
                t.text = "#" + str
                let sz = t.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
                totalWidth += sz.width
                tagViews.append(t)
            }
 
            let rowWidth: CGFloat = totalWidth / CGFloat(numRows)
            var iTag: Int = 0
            while iTag < tagViews.count {
                // create a new "row" horizontal stack view
                let v = UIStackView()
                v.spacing = 8
                vStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
                var cw: CGFloat = 0
                // add tag views
                while cw < rowWidth, iTag < tagViews.count {
                    let t = tagViews[iTag]
                    let sz = t.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
                    v.addArrangedSubview(t)
                    cw += sz.width
                    iTag += 1
                }
            }

            // set closure so we can track selections
            tagViews.forEach { tv in
                tv.selectChanged = { [weak self] theTagView in
                    guard let self = self,
                          let idx = self.tagViews.firstIndex(of: theTagView)
                    else { return }
                    if theTagView.selected {
                        self.delegate?.myTagsView(self, didSelectItemAt: idx)
                    } else {
                        self.delegate?.myTagsView(self, didDeSelectItemAt: idx)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // number of rows of tagViews
    public var numRows: Int = 2
    
    // vertical stack view to hold the rows
    private let vStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        v.alignment = .leading
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(vStack)
        addSubview(scrollView)
        let g = self
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vStack.heightAnchor, constant: 16.0),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

It will use a protocol to allow our controller to respond to selection / deselection:

```
// protocol so we can tell the controller about selections
protocol MyTagsViewDelegate {
    func myTagsView(_ myTagsView: MyTagsView, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
    func myTagsView(_ myTagsView: MyTagsView, didDeSelectItemAt index: Int)
}
```

Our example controller will create 3 instances of `MyTagsView`, with 2, 3 and 4 "rows":

```
class MyTagsVC: UIViewController, MyTagsViewDelegate {
    
    let theTags: [String] = [
        "streetphotograhy", "portraits", "wild", "india", "landscape", "portrait",
        "These", "Are", "Tags", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
    ]

    let stack = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 16
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // let the view determine its own height
        ])
        
        // let's create 3 tag views
        //  with 2, 3, 4 rows
        for i in 2...4 {
            let tv = MyTagsView()
            tv.backgroundColor = .white
            tv.numRows = i
            tv.theTags = self.theTags
            tv.delegate = self
            stack.addArrangedSubview(tv)
        }
        
    }
    func myTagsView(_ myTagsView: MyTagsView, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {
        guard let tvIDX = stack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: myTagsView) else { return }
        print("Selected: \(index) / \"\(theTags[index])\" in tags view \(tvIDX)")
    }
    func myTagsView(_ myTagsView: MyTagsView, didDeSelectItemAt index: Int) {
        guard let tvIDX = stack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: myTagsView) else { return }
        print("Deselected: \(index) / \"\(theTags[index])\" in tags view \(tvIDX)")
    }
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

This is just an idea of ***one other approach*** ... and is just starter code to play with to see if it would be a workable alternative.