# Call UICollectionViewDataSource method from UICollectionViewLayout subclass

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm writing my own `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass to have full control over the layout and arrangement of my collection view cells. When computing the item sizes, I want the layout to start with the cells' fitting sizes, i.e. I want the cells to size themselves to fit their content initially and then modify their frames later based on that information.

To get the fitting sizes, I first ask the collection view's data source for all cells in the layout's `prepare()` method and layout all the cells using `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`.

```
let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {     
    collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: $0) 
}

let allItemSizes = allCells.map { cell in
    cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: contentSize.width, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric))
}
```

Visually, everything works as expected and I get exactly the result I want. However, every time the collection view is laid out, the following warning it printed to the console:

> [CollectionView] An attempt to prepare a layout while a prepareLayout call was already in progress (i.e. reentrant call) has been ignored. Please file a bug.

So it appears to me that it is prohibited to call any data source method while the layout is being prepared.

Which brings me to my question:

##### How can I obtain information from the data source that I need to compute the layout from within my `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass?

(Or more specifically: How can I get the concrete cell sizes right before I compute the layout?)

---

#### Notes:

1. Since Apple's own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` works with automatic cells sizes (`estimatedItemSize`), there must be a clean way to get this information.
2. Apple's *[Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW4)* states:

   > In a limited number of cases, the layout object might rely on information in the data source to position items. For example, a layout that displays items on a map might retrieve the map location of each item from the data source.

   This also means that there must be a way to query the data source from the layout object.

---

#### Supplemental: Minimal Code Example

Below is a (not so) minimal code for the layout that I'm trying to achieve.

```
class SelfSizingTagListLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var frames: [IndexPath: CGRect] = [:]
    private var cachedAttributes: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]

    let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 8

    override func prepare() {
        guard let collectionView else {
            return
        }

        contentSize = .init(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 0)

        let itemCount = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let allIndedxPaths = (0..<itemCount).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) }
        let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {
            collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: $0)
        }
        let allItemSizes = allCells.map { cell in
            cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: contentSize.width, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric))
        }

        frames = computeFrames(for: allItemSizes)
        cachedAttributes = [:]
        for frame in frames {
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: frame.key)
            attributes.frame = frame.value
            cachedAttributes[frame.key] = attributes
        }

        contentSize.height = frames.map(\.value.maxY).max() ?? 0
    }

    private func computeFrames(for itemSizes: [CGSize]) -> [IndexPath: CGRect] {
        let contentWidth = collectionView!.bounds.width
        let rowHeight = itemSizes.map(\.height).max() ?? 0
        var row: Int = 0
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat {
            CGFloat(row) * (rowHeight + interItemSpacing)
        }
        var item: Int = 0

        var frames: [IndexPath: CGRect] = [:]

        for itemSize in itemSizes {
            if x + itemSize.width > contentWidth {
                row += 1
                x = 0
            }

            let frame = CGRect(origin: .init(x: x, y: y), size: itemSize)
            frames[IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)] = frame
            item += 1
            x += itemSize.width + interItemSpacing
        }

        return frames
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        cachedAttributes.map(\.value)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        cachedAttributes[indexPath]
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        contentSize
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not surprising that UIKit balks at calling `cellForItemAt` from `prepare()`. If you can provide a minimal concrete example, we can maybe come up with a solution.

Comment: Sure. Just added the code for my layout.

Comment: OK - because the message shows *"Please file a bug."*, I suspect this may be one you can ignore. Typically (I guess), we would use a different approach to calculate the cell layout that wouldn't require calling `cellForItemAt` ... but that requires your `SelfSizingTagListLayout` class to know about your cell class and data. If you want a quick example of that approach, I could post it as an answer.

Comment: The reason why I use `cellForItemAt` in my layout is that I want to have a _single source of truth_. I've seen plenty of implementations where people use sizing cells or try to come with manual size calculations, but that really feels rather verbose and inelegant as you have two place where you decide what cell to use and how to populate it with data (`cellForItemAt` and `sizeForItemAt`). It always ended up in a mess and people forgetting to update `sizeForItemAt` after they changes something in `cellForItemAt`. Using `cellForItemAt` from within the layout was my way out.

Comment: I'm still curious about your approach though. If it satisfies the "single source of truth" requirement, I'd be happy if you could share it.

Comment: I wouldn't interpret too much into the _"Please file a bug"_ thing. I guess that might be intended for developers using the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` without modification – or any other layout provided by Apple. What worries me is that the first sentence indicates that the `prepare()` method is called from within the `prepare()` method (at least that's my interpretation) and that this is not supposed to happen. (So normally, we would end up with a call loop here, but Apple prevents that and throws the warning message.)

Comment: Yeah, I think get what you're going for... posting an answer that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, it's generally not a good idea to "ignore" the warning / error messages, even if the output is what we want. Just because it works now doesn't mean it will work in the future.

So... ***one*** way to avoid that...

To reduce duplicate code (that has to be changed in multiple places when the cell / data changes), we'll start by assuming we've set up our cell to handle its content.

So, in `cellForItemAt`, instead of a bunch of:

```
cell.labelOne.text = ...
cell.labelTwo.text = ...
cell.imageView.image = ...
etc.
```

it might look like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! SomeCVCell
    cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}
```

Since we get the *(i.e. reentrant call)* error if `cellForItemAt` is called before the first layout has completed, let's add a protocol:

```
protocol MyLayoutDelegate {
    func cellFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
}
```

and implement it almost the same way:

```
func cellFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = SomeCVCell()
    cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}
```

Next we add a delegate property:

```
class SelfSizingTagListLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    var myLayoutDelegate: MyLayoutDelegate?
```

in the controller class:

```
    // create collection view layout
    let sstlLayout = SelfSizingTagListLayout()
    
    // set custom delegate
    sstlLayout.myLayoutDelegate = self
```

and then, inside `prepare()`:

```
// instead of this...
//let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {
//  collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: $0)
//}

// let's get the cells via our custom delegate
let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {
    myLayoutDelegate?.cellFor($0)
}
```

Here's a complete example to demonstrate...

**Simple single-label cell**

```
class SomeCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    }
    
    public func fillData(_ d: String) {
        label.text = "#" + d
    }
    
}
```

**Protocol**

```
protocol MyLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
    func cellFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
}
```

**Example controller** - collection view and button to cycle through data-sets

```
class CustomLayoutVC: UIViewController,
                   UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,
                   MyLayoutDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // data for cells will be filled by code
    var myData: [String] = []
    var sampleStringSets: [[String]] = []
    var samplesIDX: Int = 0
    
    // button tap will cycle through the sample data sets
    @objc func btnTap(_ sender: Any?) {
        samplesIDX += 1
        myData = sampleStringSets[samplesIDX % sampleStringSets.count]
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // Next Data Set button
        let btn: UIButton = {
            let v = UIButton()
            v.setTitle("Get Next Data Set", for: [])
            v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return v
        }()
        
        // create collection view layout
        let sstlLayout = SelfSizingTagListLayout()
        
        // set custom delegate
        sstlLayout.myLayoutDelegate = self
        
        // create collection view
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: sstlLayout)

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(btn)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // put button near top
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // collection view below button, inset 20-points on each side
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // usual collection view stuff
        collectionView.register(SomeCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
                
        // get sample data
        sampleStringSets = SampleTags().samples()
        
        // set the first example data set
        myData = sampleStringSets[samplesIDX % sampleStringSets.count]

        // background color for the collection view
        //  so we can see its frame
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow

    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! SomeCVCell
        cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
    func cellFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = SomeCVCell()
        cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

**Custom Layout class**

```
class SelfSizingTagListLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    weak var myLayoutDelegate: MyLayoutDelegate?
    
    private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var frames: [IndexPath: CGRect] = [:]
    private var cachedAttributes: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    
    let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 8

    override func prepare() {
        guard let collectionView else {
            return
        }
        
        contentSize = .init(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 0)
        
        let itemCount = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let allIndedxPaths = (0..<itemCount).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) }

        // instead of this...
        //let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {
        //  collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: $0)
        //}

        // let's get the cells via our custom delegate
        let allCells = allIndedxPaths.compactMap {
            myLayoutDelegate?.cellFor($0)
        }
        
        let allItemSizes = allCells.map { cell in
            cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: contentSize.width, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric))
        }
        
        frames = computeFrames(for: allItemSizes)
        cachedAttributes = [:]
        for frame in frames {
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: frame.key)
            attributes.frame = frame.value
            cachedAttributes[frame.key] = attributes
        }
        
        contentSize.height = frames.map(\.value.maxY).max() ?? 0
    }

    private func computeFrames(for itemSizes: [CGSize]) -> [IndexPath: CGRect] {
        let contentWidth = collectionView!.bounds.width
        let rowHeight = itemSizes.map(\.height).max() ?? 0
        var row: Int = 0
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat {
            CGFloat(row) * (rowHeight + interItemSpacing)
        }
        var item: Int = 0
        
        var frames: [IndexPath: CGRect] = [:]
        
        for itemSize in itemSizes {
            if x + itemSize.width > contentWidth {
                row += 1
                x = 0
            }
            
            let frame = CGRect(origin: .init(x: x, y: y), size: itemSize)
            frames[IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)] = frame
            item += 1
            x += itemSize.width + interItemSpacing
        }
        
        return frames
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        cachedAttributes.map(\.value)
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        cachedAttributes[indexPath]
    }
    
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        contentSize
    }
}
```

**Just some sample tags to use as data**

```
class SampleTags: NSData {
    func samples() -> [[String]] {
        
        let tmp: [[String]] = [
            [
                ".htaccess",
                ".net",
                "ajax",
                "algorithm",
                "amazon-web-services",
                "android-layout",
                "android-studio",
                "android",
                "angular",
                "angularjs",
                "apache-spark",
            ],
            [
                "apache",
                "api",
                "arrays",
                "asp.net-core",
                "asp.net-mvc",
                "asp.net",
                "azure",
                "bash",
                "c",
                "c#",
                "c++",
                "class",
                "codeigniter",
                "cordova",
                "css",
                "csv",
                "dart",
                "database",
                "dataframe",
                "date",
                "datetime",
                "dictionary",
                "django",
                "docker",
                "eclipse",
                "email",
                "entity-framework",
                "excel",
                "express",
            ],
            [
                "facebook",
                "file",
                "firebase",
                "flutter",
                "for-loop",
                "forms",
                "function",
                "git",
                "go",
                "google-chrome",
                "google-maps",
                "hibernate",
                "html",
                "http",
                "image",
                "ios",
                "iphone",
                "java",
                "javascript",
                "jquery",
                "json",
                "kotlin",
                "laravel",
                "linq",
                "linux",
                "list",
                "loops",
                "macos",
                "matlab",
                "matplotlib",
                "maven",
                "mongodb",
                "multithreading",
                "mysql",
                "node.js",
                "numpy",
                "object",
                "objective-c",
                "oop",
                "opencv",
                "oracle",
                "pandas",
                "performance",
                "perl",
                "php",
                "postgresql",
                "powershell",
                "python-2.7",
                "python-3.x",
                "python",
                "qt",
                "r",
                "react-native",
                "reactjs",
                "regex",
                "rest",
                "ruby-on-rails-3",
                "ruby-on-rails",
                "ruby",
                "scala",
                "selenium",
                "shell",
                "sockets",
                "sorting",
                "spring-boot",
                "spring-mvc",
                "spring",
                "sql-server",
                "sql",
            ],
        ]
        
        return tmp
    }
}
```

Looks like this when run:

[image] [image]

Comment: This is a great approach and probably the best there is. Thanks a lot for making the effort and sharing it! I also chatted with an Apple engineer during Apple Q&A the other day and they actually suggested the same approach (with delegate or callback closure) – with a tiny, yet important twist: Instead of having the delegate return a cell, you only return the cell's _content_. You then call this delegate method for both the layout and the `cellForItemAt` method.

Comment: Why? Because you no longer need sizing cells! You simply use a single, blank cell type and plug in the content view – and you use the same content view for the layout (process). The disadvantage of this approach is that you don't really leverage cell recycling. But with a simple tag view like the one above with a limited number of tags, this shouldn't be much of a problem as the cells are all visible at the same time anyway and so there is no use for cell recycling.

Comment: @Mischa - *"simple tag view like the one above with a limited number of tags"* -- if I had known from the beginning this is what you were going for, I would have suggested using a different approach than collection view... Something like this, perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911305/6257435

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

##### You can't do it.

I asked an Apple engineer this question and they said:

> It is definitely not supported to have your layout directly fetch cells from the data source.

So the only way to get information from the data source from within a collection view layout object is to provide this information in another (custom) method and query this method from both the layout object and the data source ( `cellForItemAt` method).

[DonMag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag) shows nicely how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74463471/2062785). (Please make sure to also read the comments.)